# access denied for wordpress on a local xampp

Tags: php, wordpress, xampp

Xampp is installed on my local windows machine. 
I downloaded WordPress 4.5.2, unzipped it and put the contents in a folder called `wptest` which is in `htdocs`. 
`Xammp` has php 7.0.6

The error I am getting is:
    Access forbidden!
    You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is either
    no index document or the directory is read-protected.
    Error 403

If I type localhost into the browser I am taken to the localhost/dashboard
and if I type in `localhost/wptest` I get the access denied error.

When I first copied the wp files into the wptest folder I took the following steps:
Created a DB called `wptest` (same as the folder with the wp files in).
Renamed `wp-config-sample.php` file to `wp-config.php`. 
Inside `wp-config.php` I Replaced **“database_name_here”** with wptest, 
Replaced “username_here” with “root” and Left the **“password_here”** blank.

I have tried several suggestions from forum posts regarding the access denied error but am getting nowhere. 
As I have little experience with phpMyAdmin & XAMMP it may be a simple permissions setting I have missed.

Comment: Do you need to specify your port number? For example when I do local development I set my port to 8080 so my url would be localhost:8080/wptest. By Default I believe it is 80. So you should try using the url: locahost:80/wptest.

Comment: Check the *owner* of *wptest* directory, I guess it would be different from your current user.

Comment: using VirtualHost?

Comment: @AJDEV the port is set up to 80. I have included the port number as you have suggested locahost:80/wptest. and I sit get the same result

Comment: @Rajdeep Paul I have 2 users root and superadmin granted all privileges. How do I find out who the owner is?

Comment: @sakarya I am using xampp installed on my local machine only

Comment: @maggs Here's a link to give you a head start, [http://askubuntu.com/questions/175054/how-to-find-owner-and-group-of-a-directory](http://askubuntu.com/questions/175054/how-to-find-owner-and-group-of-a-directory)

Comment: @Rajdeep Paul I am not using ubuntu only xampp but thanks for ubuntu link as I have been thinking about setting it up on my windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with a older version on php?

I have the 5.6.3 version and it works fine.

Comment: the installed version of Xampp has php 7.0.6 as above.For your version what did you have to do to get things running?

Comment: I only change my php version to 5.6.3 and all works fine.